# OrmLite SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using the following DatabaseHelper with [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) on Android:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "databaseHelper";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";

    // Mind onUpgrade when changing this!
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 18;

    private Dao<Account, Integer> accountDao;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Account.class);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private Dao<Account, Integer> getAccountDao() {
        if (accountDao == null) {
            try {
                accountDao = getDao(Account.class);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e(TAG, exc.toString());
                ExceptionHandler.handleException(exc);
            }
        }

        return accountDao;
    }


    public void writeAccount(Account account) {

        try {
            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, IWAccount.class);
            getAccountDao().createOrUpdate(account);

        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            Log.e(TAG, exc.toString());
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(exc);
        }

    }

    public void deleteIWAccount() {
        try {
            TableUtils.clearTable(connectionSource, Account.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Account getAccount() {

        List<Account> accounts = null;

        try {
            accounts = getAccountDao().queryForAll();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
        }

        if (accounts == null || accounts.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (accounts.size() > 1) {
            ExceptionHandler.handleException(new IllegalStateException("More than 1 IWAccounts in DB"));
        }

        return accounts.get(0);
    }
}
```

Handled exceptions are all written to [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/).

For a small but not neglectible number of users the following exception occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `account`
at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
[...]
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: account (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `account`
```

My DatabaseHelper tries to create the table for `Account` in it's `onCreate()` method.

My first thought was that something went wrong when creating the table in `onCreate()`. Crittercism though let's me browse all other handled or unhandled exceptions for the users where this error occurs and none of them had any exceptions during the creation of the table.

Any ideas on what could be the problem here?

**EDIT**: This is a simplified version of my DatabaseHelper, the same error occurs with other `Dao`s and tables. The classes that are used are rather simple, here's the Account class:

```
public class Account implements Serializable {

    //    id is set so we always update the old object instead of creating a new one in the db helper
    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false)
    private int mid = 0;

    @DatabaseField
    private String id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String userName;
    @DatabaseField
    private String displayName;

}
```

**EDIT2:** I did an update to the app with my persisted classes annotated with `@DatabaseTable` and re-creating (or trying to) the tables in `onUpgrade()`, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you please show your `Account` class?

Comment: An of course you did uninstall the app and install it again(or delete the db to be sure that at least once onCreate (this one - not previous one without fx: `TableUtils.createTable(..)` call)  was called)? also you are sure that proguard didn't obfuscate it name?

Comment: @Selvin I can't really reproduce the problem, it only occurs for a small fraction of users of my app.

Comment: for the same version of the code that you have now? did you had any version of your app without this table?

Comment: @Selvin Yes thats right.

Comment: yes to which question? second?  then check what `TableUtils.createTable` if it is using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` add this into `onUpgrade` then increment `DATABASE_VERSION`

Comment: @Selvin Yes to the first question. The database version number never change and the table always existed.

Comment: For users where the problem occurs it's clear that either the oncreate did not get executed or it executed with no success. So as highlighted by Selvin, these particular users probably need to re-install, to deal with the first eventual cause. And you need to make sure erros are properly reported (use printStackTrace anyway), to deal with the second cause.
Same for onupgrade, you need to make sure users encountring this problem are executing the expected code and this code is running properly.

Comment: @AhmedM I do report all caught exceptions to Crittercism and for there are no reports of any errrors during onCreate (table creation). Thats the weird thing about it. 
It may be that onCreate never executed though, but the question is why.

Comment: I suggest you to use SugarORM.

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques Looks nice, thanks for the tip.

Comment: My app is working fine in motorola devices but not working in nexus 5. Is there any device specific suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you are missing a `@DatabaseTable` annotation on your `Account` class.

From the [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/DatabaseTable.html):

> Annotation that marks a class to be stored in the database. [...] You specify this annotation above the classes that you want to persist to the database.

The following should create a table `account`:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Account implements Serializable {

    //    id is set so we always update the old object instead of creating a new one in the db helper
    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false)
    private int mid = 0;

    @DatabaseField
    private String id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String userName;
    @DatabaseField
    private String displayName;

}
```

You can change the table name by using the `tableName` field in the annotation e.g. `@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")` otherwise the docs state:

> If not set then the name is taken from the class name lowercased.

Comment: The docs also state though: 'It is only required if you want to mark the class or change its default tableName'. 
I don't really know what 'mark the class' means but I take it that the annotation is not really required to create the table. 
I will try this though.

Answer (score -2):

add table name to ensure the creation. @DatabaseTable(tableName = "account")

Comment: Why do you repeat what has already been posted and discussed?